# The name 'X' does not exist in the current context - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am fairly new to C# so I suspect I'm missing something obvious but I have what appears to be a very simple case where I'm defining a datatable in C# and adding a column to the datatable's `DataColumnCollection`. I get an error in intellisense that says:

> The name `mytable` does not exist in the current context.

I also get compiler errors shown below which I'm interpreting as the results of trying to make sense of `mytable` which is not recognized.

> 1>\Controllers\OutputControllerdemo.cs(14,28,14,29): error CS1519:
> Invalid token '(' in class, record, struct, or interface member
> declaration
>
> 1>\Controllers\OutputControllerdemo.cs(14,36,14,37): error CS8124:
> Tuple must contain at least two elements.
>
> 1> \Controllers\OutputControllerdemo.cs(14,37,14,38): error CS1519:
> Invalid token ';' in class, record, struct, or interface member
> declaration

Appreciate any insight you may have

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;

namespace VPopWeb.Controllers
{
    public class OutputControllerdemo : Controller
    {
        DataTable mytable = new DataTable("Results");
        DataColumn column1 = new DataColumn("Date", System.Type.GetType("DateTime"));
        mytable.Columns.Add(column1); //Error Here:  The name mytable does not exist in the current context.
        
        public ViewResult Chart() => View("Chart");
    }
}
```

Comment: That code (specifically, the third line where you add the column) needs to be inside a method.  All procedural code must have a method as its home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let's go over your code and what each line means.

These two lines declare and assign to two class fields.   No problem.

```
DataTable mytable = new DataTable("Results");
DataColumn column1 = new DataColumn("Date", System.Type.GetType("DateTime"));
```

This next line of code is not declaring anything, and it is not assigning anything.  This is a *statement*, which cannot exist at the class level. It must reside inside a function.

```
mytable.Columns.Add(column1);
```

I believe what you had intended with your code is the following:

```
public class OutputControllerdemo : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Chart()
    {
        DataTable mytable = new DataTable("Results");
        DataColumn column1 = new DataColumn("Date", System.Type.GetType("DateTime"));
        mytable.Columns.Add(column1); 
        return View("Chart");
    }
}
```

Do the declarations of `mytable` and `column1` necessarily belong in the method?  No, they *can* exist at the class level.  However, I believe you had intended them to be used from within a method that's creating a chart, so I have moved them there.

The reason the errors don't directly tell you this is because the compiler cannot infer your intent, whereas we can make a pretty good guess.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write executable code outside of a method. You can only declare fields, properties, events, etc.

You can accomplish what you want by moving the executable code to the constructor, or by using a field initializer.

```
public class OutputControllerdemo : Controller
{
    DataTable mytable = new DataTable("Results");
    
    public OutputControllerdemo()
    {
        myTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date", System.Type.GetType("DateTime")));

    }
    
    ///Etc...
```

Or

```
public class OutputControllerdemo : Controller
{
    DataTable mytable = new DataTable("Results")
    {
        Columns = { new DataColumn("Date", System.Type.GetType("DateTime")) }
    };
    
    //Etc....

}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Pretty obvious now that I see the answer!